# Loop through dataframe and if i get the desired value extract the row to new dataframe

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I want to loop through the dataframe and if the merged_Df$language is equal to english, indonesian and scots I want to extract those rows of dataframe and put it into another new dataframe. The dataframe looks like this:

```
   language          text
1|  english      | 11 point agenda of #PTI for upcoming Election. 1-Education 2-Healthcare 3-Tax Reform 4-Corruption Control 5-Economy 6-Employment 7-Tourism 8-Agriculture 9-Federation &amp; Provincial Reform 10-Justice 11-Women Empowerment -- Corrupt Gang #PMLn #MQM #ANP #MMA #JUIF #JI #PPP

2|  indonesian   | @Tadaporn_K <U+0E43><U+0E0A><U+0E48> 555555555 <U+0E41><U+0E15><U+0E48><U+0E15><U+0E2D><U+0E19><U+0E19><U+0E35><U+0E49><U+0E40><U+0E1B><U+0E48><U+0E32><U+0E40><U+0E1B><U+0E32><U+0E21><U+0E32><U+0E41><U+0E23><U+0E07><U+0E21><U+0E32><U+0E01> <U+0E41><U+0E0B

3|  french       | RT @runawaymau: jviens de revoir ça dans ma tl @louehxoioi jui mort

4|  scots        | RT @soloistkji: do they live together or?

5|  spanish      | @Jetzmmt La última vez no pude porque me jui al rancho <U+2639><U+FE0F><f0><U+009F><U+0098><U+0082>
```

The desired new dataframe is:

```
   language          text
1|  english      | 11 point agenda of #PTI for upcoming Election. 1-Education 2-Healthcare 3-Tax Reform 4-Corruption Control 5-Economy 6-Employment 7-Tourism 8-Agriculture 9-Federation &amp; Provincial Reform 10-Justice 11-Women Empowerment -- Corrupt Gang #PMLn #MQM #ANP #MMA #JUIF #JI #PPP

2|  indonesian   | @Tadaporn_K <U+0E43><U+0E0A><U+0E48> 555555555 <U+0E41><U+0E15><U+0E48><U+0E15><U+0E2D><U+0E19><U+0E19><U+0E35><U+0E49><U+0E40><U+0E1B><U+0E48><U+0E32><U+0E40><U+0E1B><U+0E32><U+0E21><U+0E32><U+0E41><U+0E23><U+0E07><U+0E21><U+0E32><U+0E01> <U+0E41><U+0E0B
4|  scots        | RT @soloistkji: do they live together or?
```

How to get this? and how to get the count of each language that how many are english, indonesian and scots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `language` column is text not a factor. In this case there are many options but easiest imho is to use the following code:

```
new_df <- merged_Df[merged_Df$language %in% c("english", "indonesian", "scots"), ]
```

Now for counting you can use this simple but tedious code:

```
english_cnt <- sum(merged_Df$language == "english")
indonesian_cnt <- sum(merged_Df$language == "indonesian")
scots_cnt <- sum(merged_Df$language == "scots")
```

or this one that is a bit advanced but more general

```
aggregate(x=new_df[, "language"], by=list(language = new_df$language), FUN=length)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, I'm using it but how to get the count of each language?

Answer (score 1):

Another base R way is to use `subset`.

```
new_df <- subset(merged_Df, language %in% c("english", "indonesian", "scots"))
```

And then count the occurences of each language in the result with

```
table(new_df$language)
```

Answer (score 0):

The options already listed work, but here is another option:

```
library(dplyr)
new_df <- merged_Df %>% filter(language %in% c("english", "indonesian", "scots"))
counts <- new_df %>% group_by(language) %>% count()
```

This will make you a new dataframe with the filtered data and then a summary table of the number of times each language occurs.

If you want the name of count to be different than "n", you could `rename` after or you could use `summarise`.

```
#option 1
counts <- new_df %>% group_by(language) %>% count() %>% rename(num_occur = n)
#option2
counts <- new_df %>% group_by(language) %>% summarise(num_occur = n())
```